# How to remove the extensions from url

Tags: java, url, struts2, action

I have designed an application using struts2, and need to remove the extensions for example

```
www.myweb.com/register.action
```

How to remove the .action so when I click on register it call www.myweb.com/register without action extension?

I use the following

```
 <a href="<s:url action="register"/>">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer. I should change the struts configuration as following:

```
<struts>



    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>



    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="register">
            <result type="tiles">register</result>
        </action>
    </package>


</struts>
```