# What's the difference between url "login" and "login.action"?

Tags: java, url, struts2

I'm using Struts2. I run a action named `hello1`.
I input the url: `http://localhost:8081/MyStruts2/hello1`, it works.
And I tried another url:`http://localhost:8081/MyStruts2/hello1.action`, it also works?
I don't think we need the ".action".
So why do some people add the suffix ".action"? Is it necessary? 
And can we config the ".action" as another suffix such as ".go"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the extensions from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764090/how-to-remove-the-extensions-from-url)

Comment: `.action` is default extension  in   struts2. if you write anyaction that will finally convert to `actionname.action`. if you write 'myaction' then it will convert to 'myaction.action.'   And also we can change the `.action` to whatever you wish for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.action` is the default suffix added by Struts. To change it from '.action' to '.go'. Use the below in XML to change the suffix.

```
<struts> 
  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="go"/> 
  <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="SayStruts2">
        <result>pages/printStruts2.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: My another question why we need the .action suffix? I mean that no suffix also works well.

Comment: That is the default behavior of struts 2, if no extension is specified in struts 2  xml, they will be handing request without extension and with .action extension. If you had set an extension, request with no extension will no longer work. You can try.

Comment: @roast_soul You don't need the .action suffix, you can just use the no suffix version as you are. If you want to disable the .action part entirely, just use `<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/>`.